# How to run a function every time i change a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using a slick slider and I wish to add a class to the active slide 1. This is how im doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var element = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-active");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            element[1].classList.add("slick-center")
        }

    });
```

However, the function only runs the first time the page is loaded, and i need it to run everytime the next or previous button is clicked to change slides.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Track the current slide index, use it to get the correct slide and add the class on the event listener.

Comment: But the slide i wish to add a class to is not the current slide, is the next one

Answer (score 4):

slick has `afterChange` event, use the event to add your class

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  // add your custom class here
});
```